# Symfony forms ChoiceType how to add new choices from user's input

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using js library that allows user to add new values into html select element but I cannot find a way handing that new values from symfony side and dynamically add new option.

As one of the solutions I was trying to use 'choice_loader' options with default ChoiceType field and implementing ChoiceLoaderInterface like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456199/symfony-2-8-dynamic-choicetype-options/35458274) but there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in an other way with a ChoiceType but maybe you can create you own custom type :

- You can create your select element by [customize your form rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) or/and default classes set in your custom FormType.
- You can use a ModelTransformer in order to retrieve your existing values and create new ones
- You can use a simple TextType in inheritance format the data send by the form with a delimiter and create a ViewTransformer in order to retrieve a collection on the other side