# Symfony 2 - Define selected value for EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I work on a Symfony 2.8 project. The system work with TextType / DateTimeType / MoneyType but not for EntityType & DateType also.

I try to define default value on my EntityType from a value in session which is passed in parameters when I create the form in Controller like this:

```
$filter_form = $this->createForm(FilterActeType::class, null, [
        'filters' => array_merge(
            $defaultFilter,
            $paginatorService->getFiltersFromSessionByContext($usr->getId(), $request->attributes->get('_route'))
        )
    ]);
```

I have try to use `data` and `choice_value` parameters in the EntityType but the problem is the same : when I reload the page, the data is not present in the form filter while the data is in variable session.

Case with data parameter without anonymous function:

```
$builder->add('etude', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('Étude'),
            'class' => Etude::class,
            'required'  => false,
            'attr' => array('dyn-form-data' => 'cabinet,createur,destinataire'), // Champs dynamique => on renseigne le ou les enfants (le(s) champ(s) qui doit être mise à jour à la modification de celui-ci)
            'data' => $this->getDataFromFilters($options, 'etude'),
        ]);
```

Observations: this case has been returned an error message : "... passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager ?".

Case with data parameter with anonymous function:

```
$builder->add('etude', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('Étude'),
            'class' => Etude::class,
            'required'  => false,
            'attr' => array('dyn-form-data' => 'cabinet,createur,destinataire'), // Champs dynamique => on renseigne le ou les enfants (le(s) champ(s) qui doit être mise à jour à la modification de celui-ci)
            'data' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                if (null != $etude = $this->getDataFromFilters($options, 'etude')) {
                    $er->createQueryBuilder('e')->andWhere('e.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $etude->getId());
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Observations:: no error returns but no data also.

Case with choice_value parameter:

```
$builder->add('etude', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('Étude'),
            'class' => Etude::class,
            'required'  => false,
            'attr' => array('dyn-form-data' => 'cabinet,createur,destinataire'), // Champs dynamique => on renseigne le ou les enfants (le(s) champ(s) qui doit être mise à jour à la modification de celui-ci)
            'choice_value' => function() use ($options) {
                return $this->getDataFromFilters($options, 'etude');
            },
        ]);
```

Observations: no error returns and no data also.

Code from getDataFromFilters method in Form object:

```
/**
 * @param array $filters
 * @param string $field
 *
 * @return \DateTime|Etude|Cabinet|string|int|float|TypeDocument|ModeDistribution|null
 */
private function getDataFromFilters(array $options, string $field)
{
    return (isset($options['filters'][$field]) && (null != $value = $options['filters'][$field])) ? $value : null;
}
```

EDIT (24/11/2021): debug added

This is the debug of the entity stored in session:

```
etude: Etude {#812 ▼
+__isInitialized__: true
-id: 1
-libelle: "Toto"
-mail: "yolo.toto@toto-france.fr"
-origines: PersistentCollection {#811 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#810 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-utilisateurs: PersistentCollection {#809 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#808 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-cabinets: PersistentCollection {#807 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#806 ▼
    -elements: array:1 [▼
      0 => Cabinet {#805 ▼
        -id: 1
        -libelle: "Cabinet Toto"
        -etude: Etude {#812 …2}
        -infoUserByEtude: PersistentCollection {#804 ▼
          -snapshot: []
          -owner: null
          -association: null
          -em: null
          -backRefFieldName: null
          -typeClass: null
          -isDirty: false
          #collection: ArrayCollection {#803 ▼
            -elements: []
          }
          #initialized: false
        }
        -adresse: null
        -villeCP: null
      }
    ]
  }
  #initialized: true
}
-actes: PersistentCollection {#802 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#801 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-typeDocuments: PersistentCollection {#800 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#799 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-modeDistributions: PersistentCollection {#798 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#797 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-themeMainColor: null
-themeAccentColor: null
-logo: null
-background: null
-sous_domaine: "yolo"
-transactions: PersistentCollection {#794 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#795 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-templates: PersistentCollection {#796 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: null
  -association: null
  -em: null
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: null
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#138 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
-aliasMail: "contact@toto-france.fr"
-smsActif: false
-notificationSmsActif: false
-paiementActif: true
-blocNoteActif: false
-connexionDirecteActif: false
-dureeTokenConnexionDirecte: 2
-smsSenderName: null
-locale: null
-faxActif: false
-dossierDebiteurActif: true
-defaultModuleActif: true
-frequenceNotification: "day"
-objetMail: null
-lienRgpd1: null
-lienRgpd2: null
-mailEchecNotification: null
 …2
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Using Symfony/PHP:**

Take a look at this answer, hopefully it works for the version you are using, and I believe so cause it says it was added on the 2.7 version:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35941528/17089665

**Using JS:**

You can send a variable, even if it is stored in the current session, but you should do it in your `controller`. When you create your `form`, you can send variables in the render function.

Typically, you will send as an argument an object of the class you are making the form to. I recommend you use the `Entity`'s setters for predefined values.

So... a simple example, if you want to display a dropdown:

AppleController for creating a box of apples:

```
$arrayOfTypes = however_you_get_your_info(); // <- With different types of apples
$newAppleBox = new AppleBox();
$newAppleBox->setWhateverVariableWithPredefinedValue() // Here, for example, if you were to create a modifyUserInfo template or something like this, you could prepopulate this with the current info so they don't need to write everything again.
$form = $this->createForm(AppleRegistrationType::class, $newAppleBox);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
// blablabla
}

return $this->render('registrations/appleBox.html.twig', [
        'appleBoxRegistrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        'typesArray' => $arrayOfTypes
]);
```

Then, in your form, you create your `EntityType` normally:

```
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class,
     blablabla
]);
```

And finally in your template you can use `twig` and `js` to dinamically retrieve that list and put it in your new `<select>` (I believe is what `EntityType` gets traduced to in HTML).

**Also, take a look at the official documentation:**

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices